# Not able to read the rtmp stream using rtmpdump

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtmp, xbmc, iptv

Im trying to get the below rtmp stream using rtmpdump and VLC but im getting error.

```
type=video
name=Sky Sports 2 UK
thumb=http://tvnewsroom.co.uk/wp-content/section-images/sky-sports-2-ident-2010/Sky%20Sports%202%20Ident%20201005.jpg
URL=rtmp://37.220.36.68:443/liverepeater/33698 swfurl=http://97ff0e7e610f20512dbe-483e6ce63d68aeb3d05af6c054efb801.r29.cf1.rackcdn.com/atdedead.swf live=1 pageurl=http://1cdn.filotv.pw/ss1.html token=#atd%#$ZH
player=default
rating=-1.00
```

Below is the command I use in rtmpdump to play the stream using VLC

```
rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://37.220.36.68:443/liverepeater/33698 -T #atd%#$ZH --pageUrl=http://1cdn.filotv.pw/ss1.html -W http://97ff0e7e610f20512dbe-483e6ce63d68aeb3d05af6c054efb801.r29.cf1.rackcdn.com/atdedead.swf | "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" - -q --one-instance --fullscreen
```

Getting the below error. please Help. thanks!

```
RTMPDump v2.4
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GP
WARNING: You haven't specified an output file (-o filename), using stdout
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
ERROR: rtmp server sent error
ERROR: rtmp server requested close
```

Comment: is the streaming server online?

Comment: yes its online. I can able to view the same stream using XBMC Navix.